# Input date manually and/or with a calendar vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am quite new to Vuetify.
I wanted to understand if with the v-text-field there was the possibility to insert the date both manually and/or with the calendar (v-date-picker).

I have a v-text-field with a built-in v-date-picker. If I insert the date with the calendar obviously everything is fine. While as soon as I enter a number it gives me the error "Invalid time value" (after opening the calendar first, I noticed that until I open the calendar this error does not appear).

My question is, do I have to handle this error manually or is there some more practical method to fix (maybe with some props)?
Or at least if you can give me some advice on how the v-date-picker works to be able to modify it to my advantage.

**EDIT**:
Finally, for the check made by the v-date-picker, it was not possible to write manually on the textfield because the check would have started immediately at the first number entered.

This setting can be used elsewhere in your code thanks to the supporting picker_date variable. In this way there will be n variables of text-field and 1 of v-date-picker which is used to modify the main ones (in the other points it is enough to modify only the variable of the text-field with the one concerned).

I would like to insert the solution: in this way I can both write by hand and with the calendar.

```html
                 <v-menu
                    v-model="menu_revoke_date1"
                    :close-on-content-click="false"
                    transition="scale-transition"
                    max-width="290px"
                    min-width="290px"
                  >
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                      <v-text-field
                        color="secondary"
                        label="Data revoca"
                        hint="YYYY-MM-DD"
                        persistent-hint
                        v-model="revocated_at"
                        :error-messages="errors.revocated_at"
                        prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                        clearable
                        outlined
                        @blur="picker_date = parseDate(revocated_at)"
                        v-on="on"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </template>
                    <v-date-picker first-day-of-week="1" v-model="picker_date"                           @change="revocated_at = picker_date" no-title                                 @input="menu_revoke_date1= false">
                    </v-date-picker>
                 </v-menu>
```

```js
    parseDate(date){
      let validate_date = this.$moment(date)
      if (this.$moment(validate_date,'YYYY-MM-DD',true).isValid()) {
        return validate_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a second value to hold only valid dates. Here, when the user enters a valid date we assign the valid date holder, when the calendar changes we assign both. You could do some validation in the case of an invalid input date.

```
          <v-text-field
             v-model="date_input"
             @input="onInput"
            label="Regular"
          ></v-text-field>
    
    <v-date-picker v-model="valid_date" @change="dateChange"></v-date-picker>




        onInput(val){
          const newDate = moment(val);
          if (newDate.isValid()){
            this.valid_date = newDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
          }
        },
        dateChange(date){
          this.date_input = date
        }
```

https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/vYmdEXM?editors=1011

Comment: This solution is certainly valid, it worked. In the end I created the variable and, since I only have to send one variable to the backend and I do the validation on the backend side, I solve it with a simple watch that updates my first variable when the date is chosen from the calendar. So, the second variable created for the v-date-picker I use it only as a support to update the first one (of the v-text-field) that I have to send to the backend.
Any solution that uses only one variable? Because I have many similar cases and I would have to create many other variables for the same job.

Comment: Yea, if you want 1 variable you could do a nested v-model on a single object like calendar_input.valid_date and calendar_input.text_input.

Comment: And in that case you would want to use the callback approach I had above instead of a watcher considering you'd need to create a new watch for every new variable.

Comment: Thanks Tim, your example really helped me! I did not know the library moment so it took me a moment to put all the pieces together but in the end I did it. Instead of input I decided to use blur instead, so it only checks when it loses the focus of the text-field.
Also to solve the 1000 variables issue, I only created one that was used as a support for all the others. Basically I always change the support variable when I write manually or with the calendar but with the @change in the v-date-picker I will only change the text-field concerned because it is linked to its variable

Comment: Good idea, Glad I could help!